# How to resolve Angular CLI Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-colors'?

Tags: angular, npm

I have problems when running my angular project, I have installed the latest version of NodeJs and NPM, but when I run my project using the `ng` command, the error that appears is like this :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-colors'
Require stack:
- /home/illumination/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js
- /home/illumination/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /home/illumination/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/illumination/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js:10:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/skadi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js',
    '/home/skadi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js',
    '/home/skadi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng'
  ]
}
```

I have re-installed NodeJs and even I use NVM to install it, but the error still appears, I try to use the `ng serve` command and the `ng -version` error that appears is still as above.

PLease help me to resolve my problem

Thanks

Comment: For myself, deleting the node_modules and then running ```npm install``` again solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

For me installing ansi-colors globally worked:

```
npm i -g ansi-colors
```